# Как правильно сделать динамический массив строк в С?

Tags: c

Мне нужно создать отдельную функцию, которая будет считывать строку, разбивать ее на предложения, сохранять их в двумерный массив и удалять одинаковые предложения. Как сделать так, что бы я мог передать двумерный массив созданный в функции reedAndSort в функцию main?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int reedAndSort (int *numberOfStr, char ***text);

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    char **text;
    int numberOfStr = 0;
    reedAndSort (&numberOfStr, &text) ;

}

int reedAndSort (int *numberOfStr, char ***text){
    *text = malloc(sizeof(char**));
    char *string = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    char symbol;
    int schet = 0; // счетчик для поиска одинаковых строк
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int lenStr = 1;


    while (symbol != '\n'){

        while ((symbol != '.') && (symbol != '\n')){
            symbol = getchar();
            lenStr++;
            string = (char *)realloc(string, lenStr*sizeof(string));
            string[lenStr - 2] = symbol;  
        }
        symbol = getchar();
        string[lenStr - 1] = '\0';

        for (i = 0; i < *numberOfStr; i++){
            if (strlen(string) == strlen((*text)[i])){
                for(j = 0; j < strlen(string); j++){
                    if (tolower(string[j]) == tolower((*text)[i][j]))
                        schet++;
                }
                if (schet == strlen(string))
                    break;
                else 
                    schet = 0;            
            }
        }
        if (schet != strlen(string)){      
            *numberOfStr++;
            *text = (char**)realloc(*text, *numberOfStr*sizeof(char*));
            (*text)[*numberOfStr - 1] = (char*)realloc(*text[*numberOfStr - 1], strlen(string)*sizeof(char)+1);
            strcpy((*text)[*numberOfStr - 1], string);
        }
        schet = 0;
        free(string);
        string = NULL;
        lenStr = 1;
        //for(i = 0; i < *numberOfStr; i++) printf("%s\n", *text[i]);   
    }

}
```

P. S. я только учусь писать на С, по этому буду рад любой критике.

Comment: Критика: 1) лучше сначала прочесть символ, а потом его проверять; 2) после ввода всей строки вы читаете лишний символ (т.о. при втором вызове вы потеряете первый символ); 3) для поиска дубликатов без учета регистра символов лучше вызывать `strcasecmp()`; 4) `*numberOfStr++;` увеличивает указатель, надо `(*numberOfStr)++;` 5) `(*text)[*numberOfStr - 1] = (char*)realloc(...` не имеет смысла, надо просто сохранить там указатель на предложение и не освобождать потом эту память (`strcpy(...)` после этого уже не нужна); 6) в функции нет return ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Накопленный текст (массив указателей на предложения) вы возвращаете в main правильно, а вот двумерных массивов я тут в упор не вижу.

В вашем коде есть ошибки и он (мягко говоря) не однозначный... Основная (фатальная) ошибка это `*numberOfStr++;`. **Тут вы увеличиваете указатель, а не число, на которое он указывает** (правильно будет -- `(*numberOfStr)++;`).

Мне кажется, что в целом функция может выглядеть как-то так:

```
int
reedAndSort (int *numberOfStr, char ***text)
{
  *text = 0;

  char *str = 0; // текущее предложение
  int ls = 0,    // его длина
    nt = 0,      // количество предложений в text[]
    freestr,     // признак, включено ли последнее предложение в text[]
    c;           // прочитанный из stdin символ

  do {
    c = getchar();
    // конечно, realloc для каждого символа жутко не эффективно,
    // отложим оптимизацию на потом... -)
    (str = realloc(str, ++ls + 1))[ls - 1] = (c == EOF) ? 0 : c;

    if (c == EOF || c == '\n' || c == '.') {
      // конец предложения
      // если пустое предложение или дубликат окажется последним, то надо будет освободить память
      freestr = 1;
      if (ls > 1) {
        str[ls] = 0; // а теперь сделаем накопленные символы сишной строкой
        int i = 0;
        while (i < nt) // ищем дубликат
          if (strcasecmp(str, (*text)[i++]) == 0)
            break;
        if (i == nt) { // это не пустое предложение и не дубликат
          (*text = realloc(*text, ++nt * sizeof(char *)))[nt - 1] = str;
          str = 0;     // теперь тут будет выделяться новая память
          freestr = 0; // даже если это последнее предложение, то эту память не надо освобождать
        }
      }
      // для пустого предложения будет использована уже выделенная память
      ls = 0;
    }

  } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);

  if (freestr)
    free(str);
  *numberOfStr = nt;

  // вернем последний символ ввода,
  // по нему можно определить конец файла
  // (если в дальнейшем предполагается читать более одной строки)
  return c; 
}
```

Понятно, что название функции `reedAndSort` с ошибкой и не совсем правильно отражает ее суть (sort тут явно ни при чем...)